# Compression in node.js

Tags: node.js, compression, redis

I'm putting some bigger JSON values in my caching layer (redis), and I think they could use some compression to cut down my memory usage a bit.

Which compression modules for node.js do you use? For some reason everything that's listed on the joyent/node [Modules](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#compression) wiki looks fishy - either 404s, no commits for more than a year, very few people watching, or open reports of memory leaks.

[Snappy](https://github.com/kesla/node-snappy) looks nice, but I'd rather go for something more portable.

I'd naturally prefer an async compression/decompression API over a blocking one, but I'm also curious if you think it makes a big difference for low compression levels.

Thanks in advance for your replies!

---

EDIT:

**About portability**: what I really meant is that the module can be installed via `npm` and has no external dependencies that are not present on generic *NIX setups.
Why? Because certain PaaS setups (currently only **heroku's celadon-cedar** to my knowledge, but perhaps more in the future) don't provide traditional admin access to the instance environment via ssh or the like, and the only way to bring in dependencies is via `npm`.

Ideally, the module should also run on cygwin.

So what would you use?

Comment: use [bison](https://github.com/BonsaiDen/BiSON.js).

Comment: Looking to do exactly the same thing.  Curious as to what you finally decided upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say 'more portable' I assume you're referring to the C++ code with snappy. Unfortunately a native javascript implementation of most compression algorithms would be an order of magnitude slower than a native C/C++ implementation, which is why nearly all of the node compression libraries use it. Snappy is extremely portable (I've built it on Solaris, Linux and OSX) and fairly active. I would strongly recommend it over anything else.

Comment: Update: a few days ago the author of the node-snappy module included the sources of the snappy-lib in the npm, which means that a simple `npm install snappy` now brings in all dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

There are optimizations you can try before adding compression overhead. See the [documentation on memory optimization](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization).

Comment: We're already using stuff like zipmaps and the like; I wonder if the zipmap also compresses the serialized representation of hashes, or it just avoids the overhead of keeping it unserialized in memory. Guess best thing to do is to ask a new question ... or run a simple benchmark

Comment: But there is another thing that's relevant to compressing stuff before putting it in the caching layer; as mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stackoverflow-use-caching-and-if-so-how) for example, compressing larger string values before sending them for caching increases the network throughput