# Google's SNAPPY algorithm implementation in javascript (client side)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, compression, snappy

I need to use **[snappy](http://snappy4net.codeplex.com/)** to compress data from client side (javascript code), send to the server side, receive data from server side and decompress at client side (javascript code).

***Concern 1***: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387378/compression-in-node-js) does not appreciate the native javascript implementation. What do i do?

***Concern 2***: I would appreciate if someone may provide some pointer on how to go about it or a reference regarding the same.

What shall be the implication, in case the snappy algorithm gets a new release or bug fix - do I have to to maintain the overhead of updating my client side implementation? Any suggestions... ?

Answer (score 0):

You might use Emscripten, the C/C++ to JS compiler on https://github.com/andikleen/snappy-c or http://code.google.com/p/snappy/ itself